# MySQL table join depending on Condtion

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have four tables like this:
table 1: exams

```
-----------+--------------+---------
examID     |    examName  | session |
-----------+--------------+---------
```

table 2: courses

```
-----------+--------------+---------
courseID   |     title    |  credit |
-----------+--------------+---------
```

table 3: examiners

```
-------------+----------+-------------+------------+--------+
examinerID   |  examID  |  teacherID  |  courseID  |   part |
-------------+----------+-------------+------------+--------+
   1         |    1     |   3         |    5       | A or B |
-------------+----------+-------------+------------+--------+
```

table 4: marks

```
---------+--------------+-------------+-----------+------
markID   |  examinerID  |  studentID  |  courseID | mark |
---------+--------------+-------------+-----------+------
```

I want to run some queries on these tables so that it produces php array of courses form examiners table depending on examID which looks like this:-

```
$marks['courseID'] = array(
          'course'     => array(),//array of course details 
          'part_a_mark'=> array(),// array of marks of part A of that courseID 
          'part_B_mark'=> array(),// array of marks of part B of that courseID 
     );
```

Comment: No SQL statement will give you an php array.

Answer (score 1):

You can not get the expected output directly by using SQL statement. You Need to process the result of the query in a php loop statement and then form the arrays by traversing through the result.